# vertical alignment of html list

Tags: html, css

I have a list as

```
<ul class="List">
  <li>large amount of text</li>
  <li>large amount of text</li>
</ul>

.list{
   display:inline; 
   overflow:hidden;
 }
```

How can i get the list to have the same left vertical margin. What is happening now is that the text on the left is not aligned

Comment: What's wrong with this? http://jsfiddle.net/yZxbn/1/

Comment: You have `class="List"` vs `.list` (casing of `L` is different). Probably just a typo?

Comment: The alignment of the left margin of the list is affected when the line overflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a reset stylesheet? Can you provide a screenshot?

By what you have described try the following.

Also remember when writing Markup everything is case-sensitive your `List` is capitalized while in the **CSS it's lowercase**

```
.list{
   display:inline; 
   overflow:hidden
 }
 .list li {
   display:block;
   margin:0 0 0 15px
   }

<ul class="list">
  <li>large amount of text</li>
  <li>large amount of text</li>
</ul>
```